# Variables transforms in SPSS

Tags: regression, spss

I'm currently working in a linear regression in a large dataset in SPSS and would like to check several combinations of variables, eg V1+V2, V4*V8 and so on. The meaning behind this would be to have first look at which variables and their combinations work. Do you know if there is any option in SPSS? Or in other usual statistics suite, like statgraphics or SAS?

Comment: Can you please clarify? "their combinations work" as in do they satisfy the assumptions of regression? what does work mean.

Comment: I mean to analize the models they provide, R^2, vif, AIC, etc... Didn't clarify because I dont see what it has to do with my problem, sorry.

Comment: First, questions about code are off topic here.  

Second, your question is still unclear. It is central to your problem to define what you mean by "work".

Third "combinations of variables" leads quickly to a combinatorial explosion. Even with 10 variables there are 45 two way interactions, not to mention higher way interactions.

Fourth, adding variables together is not necessary. Regression does that without any added commands.